# canvas position binding went wrong

Tags: wpf

Hi I have the following xaml code:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
    <Grid local:CanvasBehaviour.Position="{Binding PointA}">
     <!-- details ignored for this enclosed Grid -->
    </Grid>

    <Polyline Points="{Binding Points}" />

    <Grid local:CanvasBehaviour.Position="{Binding PointB}">
        <!-- details ignored -->
    </Grid>    
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My point is to bind the first Grid to PointA ( The first point of Polyline in the view model file ), and the second Grid to PointB ( the last point of Polyline ). The out most enclosing Grid & 3 children elements are defined/overlapped together on purpose.

Problem: The 2 enclosed Grids are always positioned by the position specified by the second Grid. Any one help to see the XAML file problem? PointA & PointB are different.

Comment: Need more info on how PointA/PointB are supposed to affect the positioning of the enclosed Grids.  Are they relative to the Left-Top corner of the enclosing Grid?

Comment: Hi kennyzx, thanks. This whole control was positioned by another enclosing Canvas that defined dependency position property: local:CanvasBehaviour.Position & the hosting Canvas set its position.